# How to holster a weapon in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I want to holster a weapon in order to not run around like a maniac.

How do I holster my weapon or hold down my hands?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

- On PC, you have to double tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
- On Xbox, you have to double tap Y.
- On Playstation, you have to double tap triangle.

On all platforms, you can also open up the weapon wheel and select crossed-out weapon icon.

Answer (score 16):

As mentioned in a comment you can also hold the weapon wheel button (<kbd>ALT</kbd> on PC, Y on Xbox, and Triangle on PlayStation) and select the crossed-out weapon icon to holster your weapon.

[image: No weapon]